# Notifications in sap fiori

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am working on a sap pm fiori app that consumes an odata service on hcp.

I had the idea of showing notifications (like facebook) in case a pm notification is added by a user. So, i created an odata method that returns "false" or "true" depending if a newly notif is added or not. & in javascript i made loop function that has a condition saying if the method returned "true" i will show the "facebook" notification & if not nothing will happen. This works so far in my window app but when i open a second window to test it in both it does work just for one window, in the other nothing appears even though i added a new pm notif. I don't know the reason why ?

Any idea or syggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You have to share some code, some working examples.

Answer (score 0):

PM stands for Plant Maintenance ?
Does it work if you have the 2 windows on 2 different devices?
If you switch to debug mode, do you get any errors on console or network tab?

Without any coding examples, it’s difficult to analyze the issue.

Maybe the following link [SAP Fiori – Notification Channel](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/10/sap-fiori-configuracion-notification-channel/) Configuration helps: It describes configuration of the notification channel, which is a framework for the applications to deliver end-user notifications across multiple channels.
It is part of the SAP_GWFND component of the Front-End Server.
The functionality includes:

•Backend provider interface – enable / text templates / handling actions

•Backend API – manage notification (create/delete)

•Configuration for hub and embedded scenarios (connectivity)

•Configuration for push channels (connectivity)

This link [Notification on fiori](https://answers.sap.com/questions/11435668/notification-on-fiori.html) might also be helpful:
It talks a little bit about Notifications on Fiori.

Maybe the [following youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCtSeaNiq3E) helps:It describes how the SAP PM notifications can be created and monitored using a SAP Fiori application.

Comment: Thank you for your response, in fact i managed to display notifications on my fiori app by creating a method on the back-end and reading it in the front-end